# Does Stripe Connect allows to top-up customer (buyer) account?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to create a marketplace, where buyers can buy credits (top up their platform accounts) and use them later to buy products from other customers. I want to use Stripe as payment processor. I did some research and I've noticed that Stripe Connect is appropriate for that kind of business. However I don't know how to do this. Seller can have Connected accounts created. Buyer can have Customer object created, where I can store payment methods for user. How then I could be able to topup Buyer account, when he hasn't any ? Maybe I could create Connected account for buyer too but then I can't make transfers between connected accounts ? Is it possible to have such a business model in Stripe ??

Comment: There isn't really a concept of 'topping up' a `Customer` in Stripe. What you could do is collect info from your users, create `Customers` on *your* Platform with saved cards/bank accounts/etc, and create connected `Accounts` for those you wish to pay out to. When you want to move funds you can charge a saved card on one of your Customers, directing the funds to a Connected Account (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges).

Comment: Isn't it possible to create connected account for buyer and charge this connected account somehow ? I just can't believe that scenario from my question is not viable in Stripe

Comment: You can do https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits in some circumstances, but this is Connected Account -> Platform, not peer to peer Connected Account <-> Connected Account